# HBase--REST web-service--Eclipse--RESTeasy

Tags: eclipse, rest, hbase, resteasy

I need some guidance on how can i write a REST web-service to insert data in HBase?
Just a guideline,i mean what should be my steps to do so, nothing more..
It would be great help if some1 is having explanation on it also.... 
Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

There is already a rest service for HBASE.

http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/Hbase/Stargate

on centos install

sudo yum install hbase-rest

service hbase-rest start

you may want change the port it is running on.

Answer (score 0):

If you really wanna do this, you can write a HBaseDAO layer to access the hbase then write resteasy code above that. But this should only be the situation that you client use hbase data and server not in a single cluster. And that will lost the data locality advantage which hbase + hadoop process have....